# vue-slide-bar not working inside a bootstrap modal

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have used vue-slide-bar 2 places in my project. One inside a normal component which gets called on a page and other inside a bootstrap modal.
The one inside the bootstrap modal does not initialise unless i resize my screen. Here is my code for the vue-slide-bar.

```
 components: {
    VueSlideBar
  },

data() {
  return {
    sliderCustomzie: {
        lineHeight: 1,
        processStyle: { 
          backgroundColor: '#1FA0FB' 
        },
        tooltipStyles: { 
          backgroundColor: '#1FA0FB',
          borderColor: '#1FA0FB' 
        }
      },
      sliderWithLabel: {
        data: [
          1,
          2,
          8
        ],
        range: [
          {
            label: 'Poor'
          },
          {
            label: 'Fair',
            isHide: true
          },
          {
            label: 'Mint'
          }
        ],
        rangeValue: {}
      },
```

and the html in .vue file

```
<vue-slide-bar ref="slider" v-model="sliderWithLabel.value"
                            :processStyle="sliderCustomzie.processStyle"
                            :lineHeight="sliderCustomzie.lineHeight"
                            :tooltipStyles="sliderCustomzie.tooltipStyles"
                            :data="sliderWithLabel.data"
                            :range="sliderWithLabel.range"
                            @callbackRange="callbackRange">
                    </vue-slide-bar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in the methods.

```
refreshSlide(){
  this.$refs.slider.refresh()
}
```

Call it after the modal is opened. The problem is that it gets initialised before the modal actually opens. So we need to initialise it after the modal opens, That should fix your problem :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked perfectly. I used the refreshslide on modal open and it worked like a charm. (y)

Answer (score 0):

In `"vue-carousel": "^0.18.0",` this worked for me:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    Vue.nextTick(() => window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize')));
})
```